# A cyclic group of order "rs" where (r, s) = 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was given this question and I'm not really sure how to approach this...

Assume $(r,s) = 1$. Prove that If $G = \langle x\rangle$ has order $rs$, then $x = yz$, where $y$ has order $r$, $z$ has order $s$, and $y$ and $z$ commute; also prove that the factors $y$ and $z$ are unique.

Comment: What does unique mean ?

Comment: @Amr: Do you think he is trying to prove $y$ and $z$ are unique? Because the sentence has not looked like a a question!

Comment: I don't know. But if he was trying to do so then what about $x=ya^{-1}az$

Comment: Yes, sorry, it wasn't very clear what the question is... I added "prove" in the correct place.

Comment: The question statement lacks clarity. First, there is the word "cyclic" in the header, but it is doesn't appear in the question statement itself. So it's confusing: is $G$ cyclic after all? Second, $x$ is undefined. Do we have to prove that for all $x$ in $G$ there exists a unique pair $(y,z)$ with the desired properties?

Comment: OK, it has all become clear with the last edit.

Comment: @amirbd89: Can you find two elements in your cyclic group of orders $r$ and $s$ respectively?

Comment: To rephrase, prove that $\mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ iff $n$ and $m$ are coprime. The standard proof constructs a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and examines its kernel and image.

Comment: @amirbd89: Note that, after receiving any answer, you'd better choose the one which you prefer. Don't  leave your questions without accepting an answer. Good luck.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $(r,s)=1$ we find integers $n,m$ with $nr+ms=1$. 
Let $y=x^{ms}$, $z=x^{nr}$.
Then $yz=x^{ms+nr}=x$.
The fact that $x$ and $y$ commute is trivial because the cyclic group $G$ is abelian.
Also, we have $y^r=(x^m)^{rs}=1$, $z^s=(x^n)^{rs}=1$, hence the orders are at least divisors of $r$ and $s$, respectively. 
If the actual orders are $r'|r$ and $s'|s$, then $x^{r's'}=y^{r's'}z^{r's'}=1$, hence $r's'$ is a positive multiple of $rs$, hence at least $rs$. We conclude that $r'=r$, $s'=s$.
Finally, assume we have another solution $x=y'z'$ with the required properties.
Then $z^r=y^rz^r=x^r = y'^rz'^r=z'^r$ implies $z=z^{nr+ms}={z^r}^n{z^s}^m={z^r}^n={z'^r}^n={z'^r}^n{z'^s}^m=z'^{nr+ms}=z'$ and similarly $y=y'$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint: you can set $y=x^{sn}$ and $z=x^{rm}$. To find the appropriate $n$ and $m$ you can use [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic group $G$ is isomorphic to the additive group of $\Bbb Z/rs\Bbb Z$, so this is just the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement) for the coprime moduli $r$ and $s$ (in the statement for rings $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, but only considering their additive structure).

Concretely, the elements of $G$ of order dividing $r$ are generated by $x^s$ and vice versa, and among the $r$ elements of order dividing $r$ there is one, say $y$, such that $z=y^{-1}x$ has order dividing $s$. One has $x=yz$ and $y,z$ commute (they are both in the group $G$ generated by $x$); if either the order of $y$ were a strict divisor of $r$ or the order of $z$ were a strict divisor of $s$ then it would follows that the order of $x$ is a strict divisor of $rs$, which is false, so the orders of $y,z$ are respectively exactly $r,s$. Concretely you can find $y,z$ by writing $1=\gcd(r,s)=ar+bs$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm; then $y=x^{bs}$ and $z=x^{ar}$.